# Keeping id continuity after deletion of rows

Tags: postgresql

How can you keep the continuity of id after deleting a row?

For example: You have 10 rows in a table and then you delete the last 5, so the next creation will be id 11, but 6, 7, 8, 9 and 10 are gone!. So I want the new creation to be just 6, for continuity.

Comment: There are ways to reset a sequence, but this is a strange requirement to start with. Why do you need this behavior?

Comment: Sorry I explained very bad. I updated my question.

Comment: Usually if it can be better practice to not delete a record if you have an autoincrement id, and instead you have an extra column called `is_deleted`.

Comment: Don't do it. Gaps in a generated PK value are completely irrelevant. The only job of generated value for a primary key  is to be unique. `6` is just as good a primary key as 42, -645 or 741.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a self join:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MIN(t1.id + 1), 1) AS id 
FROM tab t1 LEFT JOIN tab t2 ON t1.id + 1 = t2.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

This query searches the first `t1.id` in the table `tab` whose successor is not in `tab`.

Example:

```
SELECT id FROM tab ORDER BY id;
 id
____

SELECT COALESCE(MIN(t1.id + 1), 1) AS id 
FROM tab t1 LEFT JOIN tab t2 ON t1.id + 1 = t2.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL;
 id 
____
  1

INSERT INTO tab VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (6), (7);

SELECT id FROM tab ORDER BY id;
 id
____
  1
  2
  3
  4
  6
  7

SELECT COALESCE(MIN(t1.id + 1), 1) AS id 
FROM tab t1 LEFT JOIN tab t2 ON t1.id + 1 = t2.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL;
 id 
____
  5

INSERT INTO tab VALUES (5)

SELECT COALESCE(MIN(t1.id + 1), 1) AS id 
FROM tab t1 LEFT JOIN tab t2 ON t1.id + 1 = t2.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL;
 id 
____
  8
```

But note that this method of obtaining primary keys can be problematic for parallel calls. If you have multiple parallel threads generating primary keys in this way, conflicts can easily occur. The id column should always have the primary key constraint, and you should protect access with appropriate locks or serialized transactions if necessary.